# Every 10000th record fails when LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE into MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am loading a csv-file with 200k+ lines into an empty table on my local MySQL 8.0 database via the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command.

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\temp\\safelog.csv' INTO TABLE pt_safelog.safelog FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 lines`

This query works fine for <10000 records.
However, MySQL seems to be unable to parse integers ending with 0000, because I get these warnings:

```
Warning: Incorrect integer value: '10000'  for column 'id' at row 10000
Warning: Incorrect integer value: '20000'  for column 'id' at row 20000
Warning: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
Warning: Incorrect integer value: '30000'  for column 'id' at row 30000
Warning: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
Warning: Incorrect integer value: '40000'  for column 'id' at row 40000
etc. etc.
```

This is part of the contents of the CSV-file:

```
...
9999,2020-03-06 19:37:33,756,779,3,,,,25,1,"Bestellen","R","Ruben",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,"User log off: R",\N
10000,2020-03-06 19:37:35,756,779,3,,,,24,1,"Bestellen","R","Ruben",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,"User log on: R",\N
10001,2020-03-06 19:37:37,756,779,3,,,,25,1,"Bestellen","R","Ruben",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,"User log off: R",\N
10002,2020-03-06 19:37:39,756,779,3,,,,24,1,"Bestellen","R","Ruben",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,"User log on: R",\N
...
```

How can I load this file so that integer values ending with 0000 are as expected?

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `safelog` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `datetime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `licensenr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `buildnr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `writestate` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `hash1` BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
    `hash2` BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
    `hashprev` BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
    `logtype` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `unitnr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `module` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `modus` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `username` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `table` VARCHAR(22) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `primarykey` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `parentkey` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `secondarykey` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `status` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `bedrag` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aantal` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `data` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `datum` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `writestate` (`writestate`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `writestateTableModus` (`writestate`, `table`, `modus`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `writestateTableModusLogtype` (`writestate`, `table`, `modus`, `logtype`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `writestateTableModusPrimarykey` (`writestate`, `table`, `modus`, `primarykey`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `writestateTableModusParentkey` (`writestate`, `table`, `modus`, `parentkey`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `writestateTableModusDatetime` (`writestate`, `table`, `modus`, `datetime`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `primarykey` (`primarykey`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `parentkey` (`parentkey`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `secondarykey` (`secondarykey`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `datetime` (`datetime`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Comment: Please add table definition for pt_safelog.safelog

Comment: Do you have any triggers on your target table? Have you checked your source file with a hexeditor for non-printing characters around the id field values?

Comment: @P.Salmon added

Comment: @Shadow No triggers. I have just checked it. No special characters. All lines end with CR/LF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the csv-files contained an extra B-O-M (byte order marker) at every 10000 rows. The cause of this was a bug in the export. A solution to load existing csv-files is to pre-process the csv-files an remove the extra bytes at the start of every 10000th line.